# Rails has_many_through migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I'm creating a many_to_many association for the following models:

```
class Competence < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :behaviour, through: :behaviours_rel
    has_many :stabilizer, through: :stabilizers_rel
end

class Behaviour < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :competence
end

class Stabilizer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :competence
end
```

I believe I have to do something like:

```
rails generate migration behaviour:belongs_to
```

but it doesn't work. I simply can't get the logic of doing this migration with rails generate.

I'm trying to save in a competence several behaviours so a one_to_many relationship is not enough.

By the way, I don't want to do it explicitly with sql table.

Comment: `has_many :behaviours` and `has_many :stabilizers`


`has_many` requires plural in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ rails g model behaviours_rel competence_id:integer behaviour_id:integer

$ rails g model stabilizers_rel competence_id:integer stabilizer_id:integer

$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

See: http://www.codequizzes.com/learn-rails/many-to-many-relationships