# How to create migration script for has_many, belong_to association between user and task model in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two model User and Task.
Task would have one owner and other as workers.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :user
end



class User < ApplicationRecord 
    has_many :user
end
```

how write its migration script.
i dont know much about ruby so please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: ......I think you are looking for many to may relationship, Please use has_many through relationship and some extra attribute to filter out the owner and worker. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

You have create a separate table for has_many through association to join multiple users to multiple tasks

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    # association to define tasked owned by users
    has_many :tasks, :class_name => 'Tasks', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'

    # second association to related worker tasks for each user
    has_many :tasks_workers
    has_many :workerfortasks, through: :tasks_workers,  :source => :tasks
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :owner , :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'       
    has_many :users_tasks
    has_many :workers, through: :tasks_workers,  :source => :users
end

class TasksWorkers < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :task
end
```

Then, you load the tasks for each user using eager_load or includes joins like following or vice versa

```
  user = User.find(user_id).eager_loads(:tasks)
```

To generate the migration scripts, run the following terminal commands from the root of the project folder.
Note - You can add additional properties to the tables according to your usecase.

```
#Generate task migration script
$ rails g model tasks owner_id:integer name:string

#Generate user migration script
$ rails g model users name:string email:string

#Generate tasksworkers migration script
$ rails g model tasks_workers task_id:integer user_id:integer
```

The above three rails commands will generate three migration script in your project_root/db folder.

You can also refer to the same question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113046/rails-has-many-through-migration).

Comment: Please correct your example by showing how to have one owner and many workers :)

Comment: You're on the right track. Just your code doesn't reflect what was asked.

Comment: how can i reflect this change in the database?

Comment: i have updated my answer, added rail commands to generate migration scripts.